# USB debugging RSA fingerprint dialog not showing

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, rsa-key-fingerprint

I have Moto G4 plus Android 6.0.1
And in that I installed TWRP recovery and manually root it

When I connected with PC  in debugging mode it shows  ***Unauthorized device***

I have tried

- Updating SDK tools
- adb kill-server
- adb start-server
- adb devices
- Restart device Restart PC Updating Motorola drivers
- Changing different USB cable/USB port Even though I reset my device but nothing happens If any one face such kind of issue please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried every single step but not work me so I just downloaded Moto g4 plus ROM and install it now everything works perfectly